# Adding dummy events to Full Calendar to make slots

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is there a way to add dummy events to Full calendar to divide each day into slots in month view, that is lets say i want three slots in a day nad there is space for 5 so i add an event, then add a dummy event which is transparent and doesn't show, then add event and so on so that there are three slots there. Is there a way to add the events in a loop or something, i can handle their sorting i.e i just need to add two dummy events to each box and the rest will be done. So is there an easy way to do this short of making so many events and adding them with the real events?

EDIT :

OK the given approach doesn't work because this way instead of making slots, it just occupies the first three positions, now if it were single day events and i added an event whose start time fell between the start times of the dummy events, it would automatically be placed between them, which is what i want to achieve.

Comment: sorry, stupid question, as soon as i clicked Post , i realized i can add just two dummy multi day events, starting from the day i want the slots to appear to the day i want slots to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem doesn't relate directly with "dummy" events. But, in any case, you can have arbitrary events created by a function you can use as the source of your events, which you can bind to the `events` property.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

```
var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
   // your calendar options (...)
   events: function(startDate, endDate, callback) {
              callback({title: "Dummy event",
              start: startDate,
              end: endDate});
   } 
)};
```

This function is going to be invoked when the calendar moves into another week or month, for example, returning a dummy event for the period.

Comment: ok well ur answer was right in its own way, but it wasnt working for my sepecific problem but still it was right so i'll just accept the answer :)